# why my basic AJAX is not running

Tags: ajax

i have a program in which i am using ajax and getting text from a file named as"text.txt"
but i am unsuccessful to get the data

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText()
    {
        request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
            {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.open("GET","**text.txt**",true);
        request.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Hello world</p>
    <input type="button" value="click to change text" onClick="changeText()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

any help?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Does the debugger show the request as success or failure?

Comment: no error shown but when i click the button it stay as it is no alert is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on of browser which you used.
So you should use pattern factory to create object for ajax.

For more details take a look [xmlhttp](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html)